# Realizar una consulta si la condición se cumple y realizar otra consulta en caso de que no se cumpla en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Me piden realizar la siguiente consulta en MySQL:
 **Seleccionar los datos de todos los clientes y si tienen alguna venta incluir los datos de la venta en el reporte.** 
Estas son mis dos tablas:

## __________Tabla Clientes____________

```
create table if not exists clientes(
id_clie int auto_increment primary key,
nombre char(30),
telefono char(20) not null,
ciudad char(30),
lcredito double
);
```

## _____________Tabla Ventas______________

```
create table if not exists ventas(
id_ventas int auto_increment primary key,
id_cliente int,
id_prod int,
cantidad double,
precio double,
total double as (cantidad*precio),
constraint id_cliente_fk foreign key (id_cliente) references clientes (id_clie),
constraint id_prod_fk foreign key (id_prod) references productos (id_prod)
);
```

Comment: Ok es que MySQL es de Oracle

Comment: si pero oracle también es el nombre de un gestor debases de datos; entonces aunque le pertenezca si usas mysql, cuando preguntes solo usa la etiqueta de mysql

Comment: Va, eso no lo tenia en cuenta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EXPLICACIÓN**

> De acuerdo a lo que me respondiste en un comentario, bastaría entonces
>   que hagas un `LEFT JOIN` para que te muestre los datos que de la
>   izquierda que tienen un valor asociado en la tabla de la derecha, pero
>   que también muestre los registros de la izquierda que no tienen un
>   registro asociado a la derecha

```
SELECT clientes.*, ventas.*
FROM clientes
LEFT JOIN ventas ON clientes.id_clie = ventas.id_cliente;
```

[Enlace del ejemplo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e757598c6fb1d5cd1066ade1a7473748)

Comment: te sirvió mi respuesta o generaste otra? @oztuk

Comment: Yo ya había desarrollado un código que es muy similar al tuyo, el problema es que me hace falta mostrar los datos del cliente cuando no tengan venta; Esa es la parte que no se como hacer, ya que tu código al igual que el mio solo muestran registros cuando existe una venta.

Comment: @oztuk revisa si la actualización que hice te sirve ocupe un `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: Muchas gracias, desconocía el funcionamiento del LEFT JOIN